# How to store JSON in DB without schema

Tags: mysql, json, database

I have a requirement to design an app to store JSON via REST API. I don't want to put limitation on JSON size(number of keys,etc). I see that MySQL supports to store JSON, but we have to create table/schema and then store the records

Is there any way to store JSON in any type of DB and have to query data with keys

**EDIT: I don't want use any in-memory DB like Redis**

Comment: You don't want MySQL, Redis, or ElasticSearch? It sounds like you just want a *file*.

Comment: @BillKarwin or we can use NoSQL DB

Comment: Then it sounds like you have your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe NoSQL is best solution. i.e `MongoDB`. I have tested MongoDB, looks good and has python module to interact easily. For quick overview on pros https://www.studytonight.com/mongodb/advantages-of-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Use [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). In addition to schema less json, it support fast search.

The tagline of ElasticSearch is "You know, for search".

It is built on top of text indexing library called "Apache Lucene".

The advantage of using ElasticSearch are:

- Scalable to petabytes of data clusters.
- Fully open source. No cost to pay.
- Enterprise support available for platinum license.
- Comes with additional benefits such as analytics using Kibana.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was looking for light weight storage. can you suggest any?

Answer (score 0):

I've had great results with Elasticsearch, so I second this approach as well.  One question to ask yourself is how you plan to access the JSON data once it is in a repository like Elasticsearch.  Will you simply store the JSON doc or will you attempt to flatten out the properties so that they can be individually aggregated?  But yes, it is indeed fully scalable by increasing your compute capacity via instance size, expanding your disk space or by implementing index sharding if you have billions of records in a single index.